# Change DateTime format in Commerce Manager

Tags: virtocommerce

How do I change the DateTime format in Commerce Manager from M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss tt (US) to DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss (GB)? I couldn't find anything in the Settings to change the format.

**Edit**

It seems like the Catalog doesn't follow my OS locale and still in US format.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, we had an incorrect assumption that OS culture is used by default. I've just changed our application to use this system setting.

You can take the [latest source code](http://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-community/tree/dev) or wait for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

The date format is taken from your operating system settings. So if you have UK locale defined on your machine, it should display dates in UK format.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a screenshot which still shows US format although my OS locale is en-GB